# Having url links open in anew, named window

Tags: html, radix

I'm using HTML5 and I get the website url links to open up in another window named "collegeWin" via,  , but i'd like for all the links I click to open to that same window, not a new window everytime.  I don't want many new windows every click on a link.  I did what the book said to, using the base element and use the target="collegeWin" but no luck. Any thoughts?

Here's my  code:

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Wisconsin Colleges and Universities</title>

  <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
  <link href="hestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <base target="collegeWin" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to open all of your links 1 particular frame. Try this...

```
function callme(event) {
event.preventDefault();
document.frames["frame"].location = $(this).attr('href');
}
```

markup:

```
<a href="http://google.com"  target="frame" onclick="callme.call(this,event)">
Link
</a>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="frame" onclick="callme.call(this,event)">
Link
</a>
```

**Try this:
  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNN5G/)**

Comment: The rest of my code has links to many different college's homepages.  I want to be able to click a link and it opens up in a new window. Then, If I click another link, I want it to open in the new window already opened, not an entirely new window.

Comment: I tried that but that keeps me in the same window.  I'd like to click a link, that opens in a new window.  With that same new window open, I'd like to click another link and have it open in the same new window that was already opened.

Comment: I'm only in the second chapter of the book.  I'm guessing there is a simpler way to do this instead of using function calls.